# Logic operations (Python 3.4) - is there a way to simplify long conditional statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, logic, logical-operators

I have the following list of integers, which I need to cross compare with eachother:

```
compare = [[2,4,5,7,8,10,12],[1,3,5,8,9,10,12],[1,2,4,6,8,10,11,12],[2,3,4,6,7,9,12]]
```

Even though you cant name lists within lists in Python(I think), we'll just call each sublist a,b,c and d.

What I wish to do, is make a for loop that can compare whether any one integer is present in either 2, 3, or all of the lists.  The loop it self is simple, it iterates over all the integers in a-d, but the conditions to which the comparisons are made is quite complex, or perhaps just long winded, for  e.g:

```
    if i in a and i in b, or i in a and i in c... or i in a and i in b and i in c... or i in (every list):
        pattern.append (i)
```

Obviously this is impractical. I've looked up solutions to the issue but to no avail. Also, would the & and | operators be usable in anyway, or should I stick to AND and OR?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could use sets instead of lists if you have unique numbers on each list.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to iterate only over values in `c`, and check whether it's in any of the other lists `(a, b, d)`? Then you can use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) builtin for this:

```
compare = [
    [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
    [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12],
    [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12],
    [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12]
]

a, b, c, d = compare

pattern = []
for value in c:
    if any(value in lst for lst in (a, b, d)):
        pattern.append(value)
```

The line `a, b, c, d = compare` is using [list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to assign each of the 4 sub-lists in `compare` to a separate variable, and the expression inside `any()` is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest for this problem use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to chain all the element , then count the number of any element that you want :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> new_list=list(itertools.chain(*compare))
[2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12]

>>> pattern=[i for i in new_list if new_list.count(i)>2]
>>> pattern
[2, 4, 8, 10, 12, 8, 10, 12, 2, 4, 8, 10, 12, 2, 4, 12]
```

Comment: The way I understand the question is that the OP only wants to iterate over the values in `c`, not all of them.

Comment: @LukasGraf i think that the OP's mean by `c1-c4` is all the inner list ! cause we have 4 list ! an he's comparison also contains c ,

Comment: Ah. Since he named the sub-lists `a, b, c, d`, I first assumed `c1-c4` refer to the values in `c`, but it seems you're right.

Comment: @LukasGraf yes , its a mistake by OP .

Answer (score 1):

On Set() you can use intersection and find all values which are in both lists.

```
a = [2,4,5,7,8,10,12]
b = [1,3,5,8,9,10,12]
set(a).intersection(set(b)) 

=> set([8, 10, 12, 5])
```

[It will be explained here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: Great thanks, this certainly simplifies things when iterating over lists!

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of booleans, like so:

```
present = [any_given_integer in L for L in compare]
```

Now present has values like `[True, True, False, False]`, etc.

Then you can do tests like:

```
if present.count(True) == 2:
    ...
```

or

```
if all(present):
    ...
```

etc.